# How to retrieve data from Json using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, angularjs

I've recently tried retrieving data from a JSON file using AngularJS. However I don't know how to do this; I've attempted to do this but it doesn't work, can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in otherStuff">
  <p>Title: {{stuff.name}}</p>
  <p>Url: {{stuff.url}}</p>
</div>
```

**DataController:**

```
$scope.otherStuff = {};
jsonFactory.getOtherStuff()
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.otherStuff = response.data.components;
  }, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

**jsonFactory:**

```
angular.module('generatorMeanstackApp')
  .factory('jsonFactory', function ($q, $http) {
    return {
      getOtherStuff: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer(),
          httpPromise = $http.get('data.json');

        httpPromise.then(function (response) {
          deferred.resolve(response);
        }, function (error) {
          console.error(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```

**Example of my JSON data:**

```
{
  "name": "Blogs",
  "url": "blogs.my-media-website.com/*",
  "dependsOn": ["Wordpress MU"],
  "technos": ["PHP", "Wordpress"],
  "host": { "Amazon": ["?"] }
},
```

Comment: what is JSON return from otherStuff?

Comment: Looks good to me at first glance. Any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, the reference to the data (via service) is nested too deep, it should be:

```
$scope.otherStuff = response.data;
```

Instead of:

```
$scope.otherStuff = response.data.components;
```

You can wrap your JSON in an array:

```
[
  {...},
  {...},
  {...}
]
```

Also, if you have scaffolded with yeoman, `data.json` needs to be in the `app/` route. If it's outside of the route you will get a 404.

Comment: @benGshore Sorry, the scope binding should be `$scope.otherStuff = response.data;` - updated my answer.